# UK Visitor visa refused... help

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, egypt

How can I change my circumstances to get a better chance of getting a visitor visa next time? The refusal was base on spending 12 months’ worth of savings on 6 day trip

Comment: Just a note, your redactions arent working, I can read it all despite your attempts.

Comment: As a further note your edit history is still visible meaning that your redacted letter can still be seen. Not sure if moderators are able to purge the edit history and thus remove it but if you are worried about it (and your removal suggests you might be) it might be worth flagging a mod to see if they can.

Answer (score 4):

By reading the letter on the photograph, it seems clear to me that they suspect you are in fact trying to migrate to UK in order to get a better paid job. That is if the exchange rate they are stating, is correct. The spending of 12 months worth of saving is a simple calculation based on the salary you have stated. It looks like if you are going to change your circumstances, you have to get a much better paid job there you live. If you manage to raise your salary about 5-10 times, you are at a level with many western european workers, so i think that would suffice.